# Salt master is not able to decrypt pillar data using gpg keys

Tags: centos7, gnupg, salt-stack

My salt master is not able to decrypt the encrypted pillar data. How can I make sure that I have salt master configured properly?

I have gpg keys inside /etc/salt/gpgkeys and also have setup python-gnupg on master and minion, still facing the problem.

When I execute salt "minion*" pillar.get  it returns encrypted data where should have returned the decrypted data.

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some more digging and just got it to work :)
I had to modify the Salt Master Configuration and create soft link to my gpg keys as below:

1. Set the Following Parameter in /etc/salt/master

   renderer: jinja | yaml | gpg
2. Create gpgkeys Symlink in /etc/salt/

   ln -s /root/.gnupg /etc/salt/gpgkeys
3. Restart the Salt Master Service

   service salt-master restart